# Cache jQuery selector to new function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a question about the variable assignment of this case:

```
function one() {
    $('div').each(function() { 
      var $this = $(this);

      two($this);
    });
}

function two(el) {
  var $el = el; // does this assignment save resources

  $el.somemethod();
  $el.someothermethod();
}
```

Do I need to reassign the passed element to a new variable in order to cache it for `two()` again? Or does it not make any difference at all.

Comment: By doing this you will use more memory as you then have 3 copies of the same variable (`$this`, `el` and `$el`). The difference is tiny though, so it's just a matter of personal preference IMO.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so the implementation above theoretically takes a little bit more memory

Comment: I don't think that assignment  `$el = el;`, gives any help, you already have reference for `el`.

Comment: Those variables should be declared with `var`.

Comment: It may be useful to do `var $el = $(el);` if that is what you need. The code as it is in the question is not really useful.

Comment: @Raidri redundant to wrap `el` in `$()` again...it's already a  jQuery object

Comment: @charlietfl right, then it should be named `$el` from the start

Comment: @Raidri agree...that would make more sense